# BlackBerry JAR file problem

Tags: blackberry, build, project

I made a simple application for blackberry the jar file doesn't get created ?
when the application is build following files get created in the main folder
.cod, .cso, .debug, .jad, .jdp, .rapc except the .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The .cod files contain the compiled program code for your blackberry application, and are equivalent to jar files.

You can use either the .jad file, or an .alx file (using blackberry desktop manager) to load these .cod files onto your blackberry.